# Align button to textarea corner

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a text_area and I want a two of buttons to be below the text_area and aligned with the text area's bottom right corner to be like:

[image: expected]

What I have so far is below code:

`form with modal`

```
<%= form_for @note, :url => registrant_notes_path(@registrant), remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class="text-note">
    <%= f.label :body, 'Add note' %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, maxlength: 1000, id: "review_text" %>
    <%= show_errors(@note, :body) %>

    <div class="counter-text">
      <span id="counter" data-maximum-length="1000"><%= 1000 %></span> chars left / 1000 character max
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :administrator_id, value: current_login.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :registrant_id, value: @registrant.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

css

```
.modal-footer {
    border-top: 0 none;
}

.counter-text {
  border-top: 0 none;
  text-align: right;
}

#review_text {
  min-height: 54px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen) of it and share it? So it is easier for us to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add padding-right:0; to .moadal-footer

```
 .modal-footer {
 border-top: 0 none;
  padding-right:0;
 }
```

add modal-footer section after div modal-body

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-right:0">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

end

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```